# how to calculate two geometry distance via meters in NetTopologySuite?

Tags: c#, gis, nettopologysuite

I use PGSQL to get geometry data.

```
 var hca = new WKTReader().Read(
        $"SRID=4326;{hcaShape}");
 var point = new GeometryFactory().CreatePoint(new Coordinate(x, y));
 var res = hca.Distance(point)
```

The result Shows like:'0.00009xxx'
But I want meters.

Also important thing is this case is **not point to point.**
How to convert result to meters?（I'm new with NetTopologySuite）

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I completed this task by using [ProjNet](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/ProjNet4GeoAPI) to project the geometries to a metric `CoordinateSystem`

```
public static NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Geometry ProjectGeometry(NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Geometry geom,
    string fromWkt, string toWkt)
{
    var sourceCoordSystem = new CoordinateSystemFactory().CreateFromWkt(fromWkt);
    var targetCoordSystem = new CoordinateSystemFactory().CreateFromWkt(toWkt);

    var trans = new CoordinateTransformationFactory().CreateFromCoordinateSystems(sourceCoordSystem,
        targetCoordSystem);

    var projGeom = Transform(geom, transform: trans.MathTransform);

    return projGeom;
}
```